# Excluding matching records from Tabular Join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, attribute-joins

This may be slightly esoteric and I suspect it just can't be done but I have found myself in the following situation.

I have a roads layer with a routeid (short integer) field. This field has been used for state route numbers as well as county route numbers. Unfortunately the numbers overlap so there can be a state route 40 and a county route 40. I have a joined table that is only relevant to county roads. The problem is that the information (including incorrect road names) shows up when this table is joined to the roads layer based on that routeid field (in records for state routes). I have ways (other fields) to determine whether it is a state or county route but I don't see any way to exclude table records from the join based on other fields. Am I wrong? Wouldn't it be nice to be able to join based on an "AND" expression instead of a single field?

I'd like to avoid a schema change where I have to add a new field and use that for the state route numbers. Currently that or separating County roads with a definition query and only joining those seem to be my only realistic choices.

The table and the feature class are both in a SQL Server Database.

Comment: Maybe the [Make Query Table tool](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/7223) would work.

Comment: Unless you are willing to move your data into a real SQL database and manage your data there, your best shot would probably using query tables - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31117/creating-join-based-on-multiple-fields-using-arcgis-desktop

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Can you explain what you mean about moving into a "real SQL" database? Are you saying I could do this with SQL Queries in something like SQL Server Management Studio? I need to display it in ArcMap this way for other users.

Comment: @jbchurchill, sure, just create plain SQL views from the feature class including the shape column. For your users it will look as a spatial table which they will be able to draw in ArcMap. I thought you are storing the data inside a file gdb