# Join two Tables based on two common columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-joins

Let's say I have two time series shapefiles and I want to join them based on the common values in `ID` (not ArcGIS created ID) and `Date` column. Currently I am using `join via table attributes`, but the output is messed up as the values don't align based on both `ID`
and `Date`, just `ID`.

How can I do this in `ArcMap` `10.7`?

Sample data 1

```
ID X  Y  Date     Var1
a  X1 Y1 1/1/2020 1
a  X1 Y1 1/2/2020 2
b  X2 Y2 1/1/2020 3
b  X2 Y2 1/2/2020 4
```

Sample data 2

```
ID X  Y  Date     Var2
a  X1 Y1 1/1/2020 5
a  X1 Y1 1/2/2020 6
b  X2 Y2 1/1/2020 7
b  X2 Y2 1/2/2020 8
```

Incorrect output using table attribute join based on `ID`:

```
ID X  Y  Date     Var1 Date     Var2
a  X1 Y1 1/1/2020 1    1/1/2020 5 
a  X1 Y1 1/2/2020 2    1/1/2020 5
b  X2 Y2 1/1/2020 3    1/1/2020 7
b  X2 Y2 1/2/2020 4    1/1/2020 7
```

Desired output

```
ID X  Y  Date     Var1 Date         Var2
a  X1 Y1 1/1/2020 1    1/1/2020     5
a  X1 Y1 1/2/2020 2    1/2/2020     6
b  X2 Y2 1/1/2020 3    1/1/2020     7
b  X2 Y2 1/2/2020 4    1/2/2020     8
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating join based on multiple fields using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31117/creating-join-based-on-multiple-fields-using-arcgis-desktop)

Comment: @Taras, the answer of that question puts all the column values in a single row, which is not what I want. Plus I am not that familiar with `arcpy` as I use `R`, so I am looking for an interactive way of doing this in `ArcMap`.

Comment: @Taras, I just also tried `Make Query Table`, but under `Key Fields`, the date column is not showing for selection, otherwise I cloud have used a combination of fields (ID and Date) that can be used to uniquely identify a row in the query.

Comment: Maybe convert a column with date into a column as a string type.

Comment: I used `FID` as the common field since the number of records in both the tables are the same, so it solved the problem as now the correct values correspond to the correct `ID` and `Date` since `FID` are created in sequence from 1st to last value. However there might be a better way of doing this in `ArcMap`.